# What would happen if there was a zone of supercooled air over open ocean?

Tags: science-fiction, weather

Suppose some government is testing a weather control device. The weather control device can control air temperature within a cube 40 feet to a side, centered on itself, rapidly lowering it's temperature over five seconds to a target temperature. This effect lasts four about six hours until the machine must recharge or be replaced. The device is intangible and otherwise does not interact in any way with the air.

The ambient air and ocean temperature is 20° Celsius

My question is, how does this effect the weather at a target temperature of:
120° Celsius
-80° Celsius and -200° Celcius  ?

IE: Does it cause a localized hurricane that doesn't move? Does it just make it rain? Does the coldest temperature cause the oxygen in the air to condense, causing a localized ice storm? How localized is the change? Does it behave differently over land and water?

Comment: nothing, the volume is too small. bump a liter of liquid nitrogen, smog all u have. it could do certain turbulence flow around itself, like inverse chimney pipe but less pronounced.  need a gigantic setup of those to make noticeable effects on a large scale.

Comment: @MolbOrg DO the math. In 5 seconds, a volume of 64000cubic feet (about 1800m3) of air is transformed from gas to liquid. this liquid has virtually zero volume, compared to the gas. assuming all 5 sides of your cube are open, you have air flowing in at about 35km/h. Then the liquid falls to the ocean below, and very rapidly heats up in the warmer water, causing outward airflow at slightly higher velocity(because vertical is blocked). At the very minimum you have a very rapidly circulating fog cloud churning. Its not 1 liter, its 1.8 *million* liters of air, per 5 seconds.

Comment: @PcMan is that "40 f^3t" legit way to write 64 thousand cf? 64k cf - sure it significantly more than I mentioned and the results are much better. yes, some sort of toroidal vortex/ring. it by itself will be more potent than a hand grenade, more like an aerial bomb - continuous one,  1 per every 5 seconds. something like 10Mwatt continuous cold power - weather level? nop, still far from it. 1 cubic km and we start talking Category 1 hurricane or similar, maybe more. 1/1000 of that, and yeah, strong winds and stuff. so  l'd say it needs to up the game in about few mllion times. it has potencial

Comment: What scale of effects are you looking for? The effects from this on a small scale (within the cube, and in the area immediately surrounding it) would be quite dramatic and energetic, but the reference to a "weather control device" seems to weakly imply that you might be looking more for the effects across a much larger area, on a meteorological scale, and at that scale, it's unlikely to do much that's noticeable.

Answer (score 4):

Instant fog, at all cold settings.

For the colder settings, you will get "rain" of liquified oxygen and nitrogen.
Unfortunately for you, 98% of the atmosphere is Nitrogen or Oxygen.
You bubble of cold will act like a balloon contracting down to 1% of its volume in the given time of 5 seconds. This will leave almost a vacuum.

Surrounding air will *SLAM* into this vacuum region. Where it, too, gets cooled down to liquid temperatures, causing more vacuum.

**End result:**
You have a **severe** (but tiny) tornado centered on your device's location, and streams of cryogenic liquid Nitrogen and Oxygen drizzling down, with some flakes of frozen CO2 and "snow" and haze-level frozen water obscuring vision.

Your device will also be drawing HUGE amounts of power to achieve this. We are talking multiple Gigawatts of power, depending on the volume of air it is affecting.

For the Heat setting, you would get a rising thermal. Possibly a smallish waterspout, not much more unless the effect is very widespread. About the same effect as one would get over a large bonfire.

Comment: My bad, that is a typo. The space is intended to be a cube, 40 ft to a side, AKA 64,000 cubic feet in volume.

Comment: @GnollPointer u can edit u question, just fix that, and make it 100 times bigger than that and it will have potential.